# Select id based on its current status in mySql

Tags: mysql

I have a table named **Transport_status** which stores the data of transport status of students.

```
                 **Transport_Status** 

+------------+------------------+---------------------+
| student_id | transport_status | date                |
+------------+------------------+---------------------+
|          1 |                1 | 2018-07-03 14:37:53 |
|          1 |                0 | 2018-07-03 17:05:17 |
+------------+------------------+---------------------+
```

Here transport_status = 1 indicates that student is currently using transport facility and transport_status = 0 indicates that student has left the transport facility.

I have to fetch the student_id who is currently using transport facility...

I have used "**Select * from transport_status where transport_status=1;**" but I am getting student_id 1 as a result of the query but as you can see the student_id 1 doesn't have transport facility anymore.

I have to select student_id for which latest entry for transport_status is 1.

Help!

Comment: when saying "current: you mean last  date??

Comment: what is the data type for transport status? if it is not an int you should wrap it in quotes

Comment: Current status means that here the current status of student_id is 0. So, it should not be in the list of students having transport facility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a self join to get latest row per student and then check if latest row has transport_status set to 1

```
select a.*
from transport_status a
join (
    select student_id, max(date) date
    from transport_status  
    group by student_id 
) b on a.student_id = b.student_id and a.date = b.date
where a.transport_status = 1
```

Comment: lol... I posted the same at the same time :) +1 and Deleting mine

Comment: @AnkitJaishwal the join part collects maximum date for each student  and then rejoin the same table with student_id and only rows where date is maximum , so result would be single latest row for each student and then you can check for your criteria